# pyspark where clause can work on a column that doesn't exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I noticed by accident a weird behavior of pyspark. Basically, it can execute `where` function on a column that doesn't exist in a dataframe:

```
print(spark.version)

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).load("abfss://some_abfs_path/df.csv")
print(type(df), df.columns.__len__(), df.count())

c = df.columns[0] # A column name before renaming
df = df.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}_new") for x in df.columns]) # Add suffix to column names

print(c in df.columns)

try:
    df.select(c)
except:
    print("SO THIS DOESN'T WORK, WHICH MAKES SENSE.")

# BUT WHY DOES THIS WORK:
print(df.where(col(c).isNotNull()).count())
# IT'S USING c AS f"{c}_new"
print(df.where(col(f"{c}_new").isNotNull()).count())
```

Outputs:

```
3.1.2
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> 102 1226791
False
SO THIS DOESN'T WORK, WHICH MAKES SENSE.
1226791
1226791
```

As you can see, the weird part is that when column `c` doesn't exist in `df` after column renaming, it can still be used for `where` function.

My intuition is pyspark compiles `where` before `select` renaming under the hood. But it will be a horrible design in that case and doesn't explain why both old and new column names could work.

Would appreciate any insights, thanks.

I'm running things on Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, use `df.explain()` to figure out what's going on under the hood. This will confirm your intution:

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1709748307134).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).csv("taxi.csv")
>>> c = df.columns[0]
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df = df.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}_new") for x in df.columns]) 
>>> df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [VendorID#17 AS VendorID_new#51, tpep_pickup_datetime#18 AS tpep_pickup_datetime_new#52, tpep_dropoff_datetime#19 AS tpep_dropoff_datetime_new#53, passenger_count#20 AS passenger_count_new#54, trip_distance#21 AS trip_distance_new#55, RatecodeID#22 AS RatecodeID_new#56, store_and_fwd_flag#23 AS store_and_fwd_flag_new#57, PULocationID#24 AS PULocationID_new#58, DOLocationID#25 AS DOLocationID_new#59, payment_type#26 AS payment_type_new#60, fare_amount#27 AS fare_amount_new#61, extra#28 AS extra_new#62, mta_tax#29 AS mta_tax_new#63, tip_amount#30 AS tip_amount_new#64, tolls_amount#31 AS tolls_amount_new#65, improvement_surcharge#32 AS improvement_surcharge_new#66, total_amount#33 AS total_amount_new#67]
+- FileScan csv [VendorID#17,tpep_pickup_datetime#18,tpep_dropoff_datetime#19,passenger_count#20,trip_distance#21,RatecodeID#22,store_and_fwd_flag#23,PULocationID#24,DOLocationID#25,payment_type#26,fare_amount#27,extra#28,mta_tax#29,tip_amount#30,tolls_amount#31,improvement_surcharge#32,total_amount#33] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/Users/charlie/taxi.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<VendorID:int,tpep_pickup_datetime:string,tpep_dropoff_datetime:string,passenger_count:int,...


>>> df = df.where(col(c).isNotNull())
>>> df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [VendorID#17 AS VendorID_new#51, tpep_pickup_datetime#18 AS tpep_pickup_datetime_new#52, tpep_dropoff_datetime#19 AS tpep_dropoff_datetime_new#53, passenger_count#20 AS passenger_count_new#54, trip_distance#21 AS trip_distance_new#55, RatecodeID#22 AS RatecodeID_new#56, store_and_fwd_flag#23 AS store_and_fwd_flag_new#57, PULocationID#24 AS PULocationID_new#58, DOLocationID#25 AS DOLocationID_new#59, payment_type#26 AS payment_type_new#60, fare_amount#27 AS fare_amount_new#61, extra#28 AS extra_new#62, mta_tax#29 AS mta_tax_new#63, tip_amount#30 AS tip_amount_new#64, tolls_amount#31 AS tolls_amount_new#65, improvement_surcharge#32 AS improvement_surcharge_new#66, total_amount#33 AS total_amount_new#67]
+- *(1) Filter isnotnull(VendorID#17)
   +- FileScan csv [VendorID#17,tpep_pickup_datetime#18,tpep_dropoff_datetime#19,passenger_count#20,trip_distance#21,RatecodeID#22,store_and_fwd_flag#23,PULocationID#24,DOLocationID#25,payment_type#26,fare_amount#27,extra#28,mta_tax#29,tip_amount#30,tolls_amount#31,improvement_surcharge#32,total_amount#33] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(VendorID#17)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/Users/charlie/taxi.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(VendorID)], ReadSchema: struct<VendorID:int,tpep_pickup_datetime:string,tpep_dropoff_datetime:string,passenger_count:int,...
```

From bottom to top: `FileScan` to read the data, `Filter` to discard unneeded data, `Project` to apply the alias. It's a sensible way for Spark to construct its DAG - discard data as eagerly as possible so you don't waste time operating on it - but as you've noticed, it can lead to unexpected behavior. If you'd like to avoid this, use `df.checkpoint()` to materialize the DataFrame prior to your `df.where()` statement - this will give you the expected error when you attempt to reference the old column name:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("file:/tmp/")
>>> df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).csv("taxi.csv")
>>> c = df.columns[0]
>>> df = df.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}_new") for x in df.columns]) 
>>> df = df.checkpoint()
>>> df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[VendorID_new#51,tpep_pickup_datetime_new#52,tpep_dropoff_datetime_new#53,passenger_count_new#54,trip_distance_new#55,RatecodeID_new#56,store_and_fwd_flag_new#57,PULocationID_new#58,DOLocationID_new#59,payment_type_new#60,fare_amount_new#61,extra_new#62,mta_tax_new#63,tip_amount_new#64,tolls_amount_new#65,improvement_surcharge_new#66,total_amount_new#67]


>>> df = df.where(col(c).isNotNull())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 3325, in filter
    jdf = self._jdf.filter(condition._jc)
  File "/opt/homebrew/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/homebrew/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `VendorID` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`VendorID_new`, `extra_new`, `RatecodeID_new`, `mta_tax_new`, `DOLocationID_new`].;
'Filter isnotnull('VendorID)
+- LogicalRDD [VendorID_new#51, tpep_pickup_datetime_new#52, tpep_dropoff_datetime_new#53, passenger_count_new#54, trip_distance_new#55, RatecodeID_new#56, store_and_fwd_flag_new#57, PULocationID_new#58, DOLocationID_new#59, payment_type_new#60, fare_amount_new#61, extra_new#62, mta_tax_new#63, tip_amount_new#64, tolls_amount_new#65, improvement_surcharge_new#66, total_amount_new#67], false

>>>
```

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. Thanks for answering. I did try materializing the dataframe with `df.cahe()` and `df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)` but neither made a difference. Good to learn some helpful tricks. Thanks again.